# How to get api information from WooCommerce software add-on with Python and WC-API

Tags: python-3.x, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm trying to figure out how I can get license keys from WooCommerce Software Addon with the help of Python and the WooCommerce Api.. The endpoints available don't seem to work.. Does anyone here has a clue on how to get things going combining the above...?

With kind regards,

Douwe

According to the documentation of the WC-Api (http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction)

print(wcapi.get("api-keys").json())
Should return information because it's an endpoint added by the software add-on of WooCommerce (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/software-add-on/). But this returns a failed connection with: {'code': 'rest_no_route', 'message': 'No route was found matching the URL and request method', 'data': {'status': 404}} as the message.

{'code': 'rest_no_route', 'message': 'No route was found matching the URL and request method', 'data': {'status': 404}}

Answer (score 0):

I just found the same problem, solved the following way for my case:

```py
from woocommerce import API

wcapi = API(
    url = 'foo.bar.com',
    consumer_key = 'yourKeyHere',
    consumer_secret = 'yourSecretHere',
    version = 'wc/3'
)

def checkLicence(key: str, product: str, version: str, email: str) -> bool:
    endpoint = "?wc-api=software-api"

    first = "&request=check&email=%s" % (email)
    second = "&licence_key=%s" % (key)
    third = "&product_id=%s&version=%s" % (product, version)

    r = wcapi.get(endpoint + first + second + third)

    if 200 == r.status_code:
        success = r.json()['success']

        return success
    else:
        return False
```

If you do not recognize the type notation, it's [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) that is used in the company I work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

Before you start you'll need to install the libraries below if you haven't already. You can use pip like so:

```
pip install WooCommerce
pip install requests
```

The code:

```
from woocommerce import API
import requests

wcapi = API(
    url="website_url", 
    consumer_key="consumerkey", # You can find it on your woocommerce dashboard 
    consumer_secret="consumersecret", # You can find it on your woocommerce dashboard 
    version="wc/v3"
)

licence_email = "email" # the email that is associated with the licence
licence = "licence" # the licecne itself
product = "product_name" # The name of the product which you sell the licence for
website_url = "url" # set the website url
request = wcapi.get(f"{website_url}/?wc-api=software-api&request=check&email={licence_email}&request=check&license_key={licence}&request=check&product_id={product}")
request_check = request.text

if "error" and "Invalid License Key" and "101" and "No matching license key exists" and "false" in request_check: # check what it returns
    dosomething() # here you can print an error or do whatever you want

if "error" and "Invalid License Key" and "101" and "No matching license key exists"and "false" not in request_check: # If no error occured, activate the licence (you can choose how many time a licence can be activated on your woocommerce dashboard)
    activation = wcapi.get(f"{website_url}/?wc-api=software-api&request=activation&email={licence_email}&request=activation&license_key={licence}&request=activation&product_id={product}")
    activation # run the activation

activation_check = activation.text
if "activated" and ":true" and "0 out of 1 activations remaining" in activation_check: # check if licence is already activate (if it is then do something)
    dosomething()

if "error" and "Exceeded maximum number of activations" and "103" and "Remaining activations is equal to zero" and "false" in activation_check: # check if licence exceeded the maximum number of activations
    dosomething() # here you can print error or whatever you want
```